# how to pass some "statistics" from c# program to another program?

Tags: c#

I have command-line program that "do a lot of work" and produce "a lot of statistics". It's stocks trading software pretty critical to delays, bugs, and whatever, so I don't want to add GUI to it. (moreover GUI is required sometimes, but console application should be always launched)

I need GUI to friendly display collected statistic (in read-only mode). How to transfer that statistics? It would be enough to refresh it every second. I need to transfer bunch of data from one console c# program to another GUI (probably not c#) program, in future probably by network, but locally for now.

Statistics is like "sensors data", measured every second. There are a lot of (hundreds) of sensors. (in real word it's a lot of different values, like "profit", "orders per second" etc.)

Should I use plain file, db or someting else and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any form of IPC (inter-process communication).

Since you're planning to go over the network in the future, I recommend WCF. If the GUI program isn't .NET, then you may need to use a lower-level solution, such as named pipes or sockets.

Comment: thanks. that sounds more complicated than I was expecting, will try to learn WCF and come back :)

Comment: btw why can't I use just plain file? I can write statistics to file once a second, and then read it once a second..

Comment: Using a file is one option. You will have to handle the sharing errors in both the reader and writer, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a database with a queuing system or a messaging appliance. A server can receive messages to a queue and then the GUI can "subscribe" to the messages.

[Microsoft Message Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing)

Also you can take a look at memory mapped files:

[Memory-mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)

These can be shared amongst applications simultaneously when configured properly.

Hope that helps,

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more efficient and resilient to have the 'server' store it's information within a Database and have the 'client' poll this as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at a technology like [DDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Distribution_Service). There are no databases involved and it is not hard to implement. I began looking at [OpenSplice DDS](http://www.prismtech.com/opensplice) recently. There are a number of different implementations out there.

Comment: @Stephen: Indeed. You should check it out. I really like it.

Answer (score 0):

This is going way beyond a single comment of course. What you will eventually need is a dispatching mechanism to notify subscribers about the data record update. Since the amount of data is huge, you might not want to opt for a persistence storage. If the dispatching to multiple subscribers looks overwhelming so far, you can go with a simple interproc (via shared object (aka named pipes) for the consumer-provider to be on the same machine or something more distributed otherwise)