# collecting statistics via callback method

Tags: c#, oop

I'm tring to pass "statistics" from one program to another (my first question is here [how to pass some "statistics" from c# program to another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472633/how-to-pass-some-statistics-from-c-program-to-another-program))
To pass statistics I first need to collect it.
I've decided to implement central storage, like `StatisticsStorage` with one method `StatisticsStorage.joinStatistics(string groupName, string indicatorName, callback getValueMethod)`

Then for example Thermometer class should look like that (pseudo code):

```
class Thermometer {
    Thermometer(string installationPlace) {
        StatisticsStorage.joinStatistics("temperature", installationPlace, this.getThermometerValue);
    }
    callback double getThermometerValue {
        return this.thermometerValue;
    }
    private double thermometerValue;
    //.....
}
```

StatisticsStorage should call callBack method for all indicators periodically.
Once statistics is collected I can pass it one way or another.

Questions:

- do you see any problems with my approach?
- how to implement callbacks on c# better? (i'm pretty novice to c#)

Comment: Observer pattern may be an option

Comment: In particular, a typical C# implementation of the Observer pattern uses INotifyPropertyChanged.  This is preferable to calling back to something concrete like a Statistics service; a thermometer shouldn't know it is being used to collect statistics, but it might provide a more general way of notifying that it has changed.  A statistics service can listen for those changes (or changes in any type of object it wants to monitor) rather than having to use special objects that know about their use in statistics.

Comment: Thermometer doesn't say "Hey, my sensor data is updated". You are going to thermometer and check current temperature. I want to garantee that statistics is always up to date. Someone may forget to call observer method. I want directly access desired field for current value.

Comment: "a thermometer shouldn't know it is being used to collect statistics" - disagree. Thermometer KNOW it is being used to collect statistics, that's why thermometer has *display*, but doesn't have *beeper* to signal that temperature is changed

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx - the thermometer app can host a WCF service and the other process can simply call that to query the current value

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to achieve your desire result.
I would probably publish a WCF service, maybe hosted in a windows service, and you can connect and post stats on that.  This will keep a good separation of system concerns and can be reused from other systems etc etc.
I suppose it depends on how in depth you want to go and the requirements in this scenario.

Then again, i could just be over analyzing what you are trying to do :)